# Unauthorized error while trying to create a new namespace in K8S

Tags: https, kubernetes, unauthorized, fabric8

I am trying to create a namespace on a K8s cluster on Azure using teh fabric8 java client . Here is the code

```
 @Before
    public void setUpK8sClient() {
    apiServer = "";
    config = new ConfigBuilder().withMasterUrl(apiServer).withUsername("user").withPassword("pass").build();
    client = new DefaultKubernetesClient(config);
    System.setProperty(Config.KUBERNETES_TRUST_CERT_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "true");


    }

    @Test
    public void getClientVersion() {
    System.out.println("Client version "+client.getApiVersion());
    }

    @Test
    public void createNamespace() {
    Namespace myns = client.namespaces().createNew()
        .withNewMetadata()
        .withName("myns")
        .addToLabels("a", "label")
        .endMetadata()
        .done();
    System.out.println("Namespace version " + myns.getStatus());
    }
```

This gives me the following error

i

```
o.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: POST at: "https://...api/v1/namespaces. Message: Unauthorized! Token may have expired! Please log-in again. Unauthorized
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Can you use these credentials through `kubectl` to check if they work?

Comment: thanks, that did help me move further. Those credentials did not work for me, so I tried kubectl config view that gave me a token which I used in the builder. Any idea how to get this oAuth token from the API?

Comment: was the answer helpful?

Comment: yes, thanks, but havent tried it out yet

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working on Azure, I guess you could follow [the instructions to configure kubectl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-walkthrough#connect-to-the-cluster) and then use the token from the kubeconfig file to access the cluster from the fabric8 client.

That token is probably an admin token, so you can also create new credentials (user/password) if you want to limit what the fabric8 client could do. [API requests are tied to either a normal user or a service account, or are treated as anonymous requests](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/#service-account-tokens).

- Normal users are assumed to be managed by an outside, independent service (private keys, third parties like Google Accounts, even a file with a list of usernames and passwords). Kubernetes does not have objects which represent normal user accounts.
- Service accounts are users managed by the Kubernetes API, bound to specific namespaces. Service accounts are tied to a set of credentials stored as Secrets. To manually create a service account, simply use the `kubectl create serviceaccount ACCOUNT_NAME` command. This creates a service account in the current namespace and an associated secret that holds the public CA of the API server and a signed JSON Web Token (JWT).